# How to enable my microphone in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, microphone

I have changed every setting of Pavucontrol and Alsamixer with no results on how to make my microphone work again. When using other live OS, it works just fine but on my Linux Mint it does not work anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I think this should be a comment, but since my reputation does not allow me to comment here it goes as an answer...

Have you checked your microphone is **not** silenced? I installed Linux Mint recently and came across the same problem. The microphone was silenced by default.

**EDIT:** Go to the bottom right part of your desktop, click on the sound icon, and then "Sound Settings". Once there, look for "Input" on the top tab. On "Device" you will see the name of the microphone and below that a bar to change the volume.

Comment: It's definitely an answer, not a comment. Any atempt to solve the problem proposed by the OP is to be answered not commented, and your answer indeed attemps to solve, and I would argue, solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the screenshot, the mic should be alive at quite a high input level.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Each time the PC is re-booted it looses the mic input on my combination camera/mic. Unplug the device and plug it back in solves the issue until the next time!